# "She" or "her" for describing a character's point of view

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I'm editing a book. The book starts with the following phrase:

> SHE, when she was still wondering who she was...

It then goes on to narrate from the female character's point of view.

> "It was over. Another meaningless day was over. Relieved, I was counting my 55 steps of something like joy."

After a few paragraphs from the female character's perspective, it switches to the main male character's point of view.

> HE, when he was still fighting with himself…

> "Another idiot was shoving documents under my nose, struggling for my attention."

My question concerns the initial pronoun. Isn't it correct to use object pronouns in this context?
For example:

> **HER**, when she was still wondering who she was...

> **HIM**, when he was still fighting with himself…

When I put it in the first person, it sounds more natural to say

> **ME**, when I was still doing X.

Rather than

> **I**, when I was still doing X.

I imagine it's like pointing at someone in a photograph or looking back at someone you know and saying, "Oh yeah, this was **her** when she still didn't know who she was."

All thoughts and feedback are welcome.

Comment: There's no context, but 'her' sounds definitely wrong.

Comment: Neither one of these is a complete sentence. So... neither? Just: "She was still wondering who she was."

Comment: Please add previous sentence. You are apparently trying to tie the example to some previous paragraph/sentence. Without the context, remove the pronoun and "when".

Comment: These feel like captions for a picture. In which case *Her* is correct. As in *[This is] her when she was still wondering who she was.*

Comment: I agree that the quoted text makes no sense.  The question is clearly leaving out some context.  My impression when I read it was that these pronouns are being used like labels for dialog, as in «**SHE**, … Passing through nature to eternity. / **HE**, Ay, madam, it is common. / **SHE**, If it be, Why seems it so particular with thee? / **HE**, Seems, madam! nay it is; I know not 'seems.'» Or something like chapter titles.

Comment: @Centaurus I agree that 'her' _sounds_ wrong but in the parallel situation 'him' and 'me' do not sound wrong, and I don't see that 'her' can be wrong unless the other two are. Grammar is gendered but it isn't sexist.

Comment: @BoldBen  Good call.  But I can see the question has been largely edited since I wrote my comment.

Comment: It's not about grammar. Would you write "He." or "Him."? It would depend on context and what impression you wanted to get across. Is the person supposed to be viewed as an object of study, or as an agent/protagonist? There are more than one plays called *He and She*, and a TV show called *Him & Her*; there's a novel called *She* and a book called *Her*. They evoke different things. For instance, it's common to say "Oh, it's him!" often meaning it's the same guy who always shows up. And you might want to allude to a song or book called *She* or *Her*.